# iOS Nested UIScrollViews Not Responding

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, nested

I've been searching around on how to nest UIScrollViews.
It seems like it should be as easy as adding the inner scroll views by using addSubview: of the container scroll view. I have everything showing up visually correct but the functionality of the inner scroll views is non existent despite supplying them with proper frames and content sizes.
My code below shows what I have so far. Only the outer scroll view scrolls. I want it so that the outer scroll view controls left to right scrolling and each inner scroll view controls vertical scrolling of their related page content.

```
self.containerScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]init];
self.containerScroll.frame = CGRectMake(0,(self.headerView.frame.size.height + self.pageControl.frame.size.height),screenWidth, (screenHeight - (self.headerView.frame.size.height + self.pageControl.frame.size.height)));
self.containerScroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.containerScroll.alpha = 1;
self.containerScroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
self.containerScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.containerScroll.bounds.size.width*3,1);
self.containerScroll.bounces = NO;
self.containerScroll.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.containerScroll];

self.page1Scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]init];
self.page1Scroll.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.containerScroll.bounds.size.width,self.containerScroll.bounds.size.height);
self.page1Scroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.page1Scroll.alpha = 1;
[self.page1Scroll addSubview:self.feedPageVC.view];
self.page1Scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,500);
self.page1Scroll.delegate = self;
[self.containerScroll addSubview:self.page1Scroll];

self.page2Scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]init];
self.page2Scroll.frame = CGRectMake(self.containerScroll.bounds.size.width,0,self.containerScroll.bounds.size.width,self.containerScroll.bounds.size.height);
self.page2Scroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
self.page2Scroll.delegate = self;
[self.containerScroll addSubview:self.page2Scroll];

self.page3Scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]init];
self.page3Scroll.frame = CGRectMake(self.containerScroll.bounds.size.width*2,0,self.containerScroll.bounds.size.width,self.containerScroll.bounds.size.height);
self.page3Scroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.page3Scroll addSubview:self.detailsPageVC.view];
self.page3Scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,500);
self.page3Scroll.delegate = self;
[self.containerScroll addSubview:self.page3Scroll];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.containerScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.containerScroll.bounds.size.width*3,1);
```

Looks like the height of your content is set to 1. If a child is larger than its parent, it won't function correctly (works the same for buttons).

Also, make sure you know which scrollview you're handling in the delegate methods. All the scrollviews will be handled in the same method and it could cause you problems.

Comment: I tried setting the content size of the container scroll view to 0, 1, == subscroll, <subscroll, and >subscroll. Changing the content size is not making a difference. The sub scrollviews still do not scroll at all.

Comment: The content size of the container should be the width of all subviews and the visible height of the subviews.  The content size of the subviews should be the width of the container (not content width) and the height of their content.  The scrollviews won't scroll if the content size is equal to the actual size.  So if your subview has a greater height than the container or if your subview's height is equal to it's content height, it won't scroll.

Comment: I found the problem. The pages being added to the sub scroll views are using autolayout. Adding such a view to a scroll view causes the scroll view to try to calculate its content size based on the size of the added view. Since I added the subview AFTER defining the content size manually, this manual definition was being overwritten.